# Validation for enter amount in textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a textbox in column "amount". Here I want to enter only 5 numbers before decimal and 2 numbers after decimal like this "99999.99". I want to do this in jquery. I am using the following code,

```js
editor: { type:"textbox",style:'z-index:10000;position:relative;',init:filterhandler,cls:'com1',},
  
  
    var filterhandler = function (ui) {    
    $('.com1').keyup(function(){  
    var value = $(".com1").val();  
    if(value.indexOf('.') === -1){ 
    var max=99999;
    if( value > max){
     $('div.jGrowl').find('div.jGrowl-notification').parent().remove(); 
           $.jGrowl("You can't  enter more than 99999.99", { sticky: false });                   
            value = value.substring(0,5);                 
               $(".com1").val(value);                      
               value = value.substring(0,3);               
    }   
       }else{ 
           var max = 2; 
           var v=value.split("."); 
           var fstvalue= v[0]; 
           var scndValue=v[1]; 
           $('.com1').css({ "border-color": "rgb(153, 188, 232)"}); 
           if(scndValue.length > max){              
         $('div.jGrowl').find('div.jGrowl-notification').parent().remove(); 
                   $.jGrowl("You can't  enter more than 99999.99", { sticky: false });  
                   scndValue = scndValue.substring(0,2);  
                   value=fstvalue+"."+scndValue;                 
                   $(".com1").val(value);                        
           } 
          }
});      
};
```

Please help me, In this code how to restrict the value.

Answer (score 2):

Use Regex to test if the input matches your input range. **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qc7zkwwh/)**

`([1-9]{1,5})` limits the first 5 characters to only numbers and cannot start with a 0. 
`(\.([0-9]{2})?` limits the user to only 2 places after the `.` and is also a lazy selector meaning this doesn't have to apply. Example: 123 will match while 123.23 matches as well.

```js
$('input').blur(function() {
    
    var pat = /([1-9]{1,5})(\.([0-9]){2})?/g;
    
    if ( pat.test(this.value) ) {
        console.log("You're Good!");   
    } else {
        console.log('No match!');   
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expression instead!

```
function validateAmount(amount){
   var re = /^\d{1,5}(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
   return re.test(amount);
}
```

Usage:

```
if(validateAmount(20.2)) console.log('validated');
else console.log('validation failed');
```

Explination:

```
\d //for digits
{1,5} // min 1 char to max 5 chars
\. // to escape char .
\d //again digits
{0,2} again min 0 to max 2 chars
? //for optional, as after decimal points are optional, it's needed to be be wrapped in parentheses.
```

Comment: Here, I can enter more than 5 char before decimal and more than 2 for after decimal. I wont allow to enter more than more that "99999.99". If I enter more than means it won't allow to enter. How can I restrict?

Comment: you can use that function "validateAmount" .. see fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bmwhoLb1/

Comment: It is working. But it is allowing to enter more than "99999.99". After pressing test only its showing false message. I don't allow to enter. If I enter the amount in textbox, I want to display only lesser than or equal to 99999.99 only.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is add, "input.js" file first. And then use the following 2 lines. Its working perfectly.

```js
    var inputConfig = {aSep:'', aNeg:'', mDec:2, mNum:5};   
    $('.com1').autoNumeric(inputConfig);
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you just use math like so?

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    amount = $('.amount').val();
  if(amount > 9999.99) {
    alert('you cannot enter more than 9999.99');
  } else {
    alert('all good here');
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/tugimayiro/1/

Comment: Its not what I am asking. Do not allow to enter more than 99999.99 means, I want to enter only 8 characters including (.) dot.